# Dosbox DEBUG: Printing any 30 ASCII characters in descending order (Hex)

Tags: debugging, ascii, dosbox

I am working with the dosbox debug program and I have been asked to print any 30 ASCII characters (0-255) within dosbox in descending order. I have gotten to the point where I can print the ASCII characters from 20-FE (hex) in ascending order. Obviously thats more than 30, so I need to pick 30 of those (20-3D) and print them in descending order (3D-20). My current code looks like this:

```
-A 100
0939:0100 MOV AH,2
0939:0102 MOV DL,20
0939:0104 INT 21
0939:0106 INC DL
0939:0108 CMP DL,FE
0939:010B JNE 104
0939:010D INT 20
0939:010F <ENTER KEY> (being the end of the program)
```

This does just as you would expect it to and prints the ASCII characters from 20-FE in ascending order. Is there a way that I can morph my code into printing ASCII characters 20-3D in the order of 3D-20? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course it's possible: just start from 3D and do decrements instead of increments until you hit 20.

Comment: @Ruslan so then would I just use the same code replacing the inc with a dec?